# Create lists of values reading data from csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need your help. I have a .csv "orders.csv"  made in this way:

```
name          | number_of_orders | eurosxp
fried chips        100               2  
fried chicken       25               5
salad one           20               5
salad two           10               5
```

( and so on)

I'm trying to create a script in python to read this data and to do calculations, so with pandas, I'm trying to create a tab/list of values that I can recall in a framework...so I wrote this that doesn't work. Someone can help?

```
import numpy as np

import os
import math

import pandas as pd



class MenuNfeedback:

    data = pd.read_csv("orders.csv", header=None)


    def __init__(self) -> None:
        



      def name_dishes(self):
          '''dishes name'''
          for j in range(0, (self.data.iloc[j][0])):
              nameDishes = list(str(j) )
        
          return nameDishes


    def numb_ord(self):
        '''How many times was orderes'''
        orderNumb_list=[]
        orderNumb=self.data.iloc[i][1]
        for i in range(0, len(self.data.iloc[i][1])):
            orderNumb=self.data.iloc[i][1]
            orderNumb_list.append(orderNumb)

        return carbon_list



    def eurosxp(self):
        '''List of prices'''
        prices_f=[]
        for i in range(0, len(self.data.iloc[i][1])):
           prices_f.append(self.data.iloc[i][2])
        
        return prices_f
```

I see many errors and I started from few time to use/call functions

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide some expected output based on the provided df?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda, Spyder. I see red errors (on the script) regarding the indexes i...but...I try to compile and it seems to work but it gives back nothing on the dataframe in Variable Explorer...very strange

Comment: If you provide some expected results it I would be able to look at some options, without it I cannot help you.

Comment: I try to be more clear: in correspondance of the lines in which is present the i index gives: undefined name i...but when I compile all seems to work, no errors and in variable explorer I don't see values. So the goal is to read the data from columns and create a tab in python that reproduce the tab imported, with the implementation of the functions that you saw

Answer (score 1):

Your `orders.csv` file

```
name          | number_of_orders | eurosxp
fried chips        100               2  
fried chicken       25               5
salad one           20               5
salad two           10               5
```

is not comma separated, so `pd.read_csv("orders.csv", header=None)` will not give expected DataFrame, you could get well-formed DataFrame following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv', header=None, sep=' {2,}', names=["name","number_of_orders","eurosxp"], skiprows=1)
print(df.shape)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
(4, 3)
            name  number_of_orders  eurosxp
0    fried chips               100        2
1  fried chicken                25        5
2      salad one                20        5
3      salad two                10        5
```

Explanation: I ignore 1st line of file and provide names of columns directly, I set separator to regular expressions meaning 2 or more spaces. EDIT: code ameloriated as suggested in comment

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, but your answer is different from the thing I asked because I know how to do this but the problem is to read this values and create functions that can recall them in other scripts...so I tried to do the code that you saw, and I decided to create the question because I haven't found another similar

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the file as `fixed width formatted` if the widths are consistent:

```
pd.read_fwf("orders.csv", colspecs=[(0,14),(16, 33),(35,42)])
```

Output:

```
            name  number_of_orders  eurosxp
0    fried chips               100        2
1  fried chicken                25        5
2      salad one                20        5
3      salad two                10        5
```